# Editing tags overwrites edit summary

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing

If one does a normal edit of a question, saves that and then does an inline tag edit, the system combines the edits and replaces the first edit summary by “edited tags”. Correctly the summary should be something like “⟨summary of edit⟩; edited tags“.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good find - a fix has been checked in and will be deployed tonight.